# Apt-get/Terminal can't detect CD in drive when trying to install

Tags: apt, gnome-terminal, dvd, livedvd

I can't find anything online that is relevant to my issue! I've checked around the answers here, and have referenced google and other ubuntu help sites, and can't find this specific problem or anything hinting to the issue. I figured this would be the best first place to ask!

Okay, so - I run sudo apt-get install [whatever] - had problems with the drivers for my wireless cards (found a workaround for that, don't ask me what it was, it was late at night so I don't remember, haha), and now am having a problem with python-pip. I figure I should solve this issue sooner, rather than later - I'm sure I'll be using apt-get relatively frequently.

Anyways - I have a burned image of the 14.04 Ubuntu boot disc in the drive on my device. For S&Gs, I also have a USB with the same image inserted - neither of them will be detected in the terminal, but I can read/write to them from Ubuntu with no issues - I actually burned the disk from within this Ubuntu install.

Does anyone have any idea on what I should try next? This is rather problematic, and as you can imagine, not having access to apt-get on a new install is making it difficult to do things.

Thanks in advance to anything that people can share with me!

Comment: So - I did my own digging after posting, I found a workaround - not exactly a fix but it may help someone else out, and it certainly made me able to install using apt-get - if you run `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and then comment out the first line in the file that references `# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/ quantal main restricted` it won't look for a CD that it can't detect. I'm sure there's a less hacked together way to do this but for the time being, it worked, right?

Comment: why are you trying to use apt-get with a disk? apt-get uses the internet

Comment: ubuntu live cd's don't contain packages like debian install disks do, if they did, it would be a series of 4GB disks, you need to use the internet

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: It's demanding a disk to use apt-get. It will repeatedly request that the livedvd be inserted (and then fail to find it) when I try to run any install through apt-get.

Comment: comment out the lines that say cdrom or delete them

Comment: you could start over and install a newer supported version of ubuntu from here, for 64bit: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso This is a net install iso of ubuntu 15.10 and it takes like 10 seconds to download. There is no live session, it is an install image only if you want to install the newest version.

Comment: bewilderedjackiechan.jpg

That's... what it says I did in my first reply to this post.

Comment: edit the file using: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` delete the lines that say cdrom in them, save the file and then run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: okay, then you should just reinstall with a supported version of ubuntu because 12.10 was EOL like 3 years ago and the sources in your sources.list no longer exist anyhow. http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

Comment: alternatively, see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release